# Backup & Restore SharePoint Site from Multi Tenant farm to Separate farm

Tags: migration, sharepoint-2013, multi-tenant

Our organization SharePoint site is hosted in a multi tenant SharePoint 2013 farm. We need to backup site from multi tenant farm to a separate dedicated farm to setup a pre production for testing.

I am planning to achieve it by backup & restore content database.

Kindly suggest if backup & restore content db would work or is there is any other better way.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Backup & restore content db would work,when performing tenant-agnostic backup and restore operations on a multi-tenant SharePoint Server 2013 hosting platform, you can **follow the general guidance for performing backup and restore operations on SharePoint Server 2013 environments**, see [Backup and restore in SharePoint Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/backup-and-recovery-overview).

For more information, please refer to:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/understanding-multi-tenancy#backup-and-restore